# Dompdf Laravel "Maximum execution time of 60 seconds exceeded"

Tags: laravel, dompdf

I am using Laravel Dompdf on Laravel 5.5.
I have an image tag like this:

```
  <img src="{{asset('photos_soal/9/Capture.PNG')}}" alt="">
```

It shows up perfectly on the browser. But once I try to generate it to PDF, it gives me

> "Maximum execution time of 60 seconds exceeded"

I have enabled REMOTE_URL. Even if I changed the image source to

`http://127.0.0.1/photos_soal/9/Capture.PNG`

it still doesn't work. It would be much appreciated if someone gives a workaround to this. The reason I want to use asset helper function is because to prevent wrong path to the image once the application is up for produciton.

This is my controller function:

```
 $questions = Question::where('id_packet', 2)->get();
 $pdf = App::make('dompdf.wrapper');
 $pdf = PDF::setOptions(['isHtml5ParserEnabled' => true, 'isRemoteEnabled' => true]);

 $pdf->loadView('packet-pdf.template-pdf', array('questions' => $questions));
 return $pdf->stream();
```

Comment: For anyone experiencing it, I solved it this way.
1. If you're using big CSS like Bootstrap framework, it will be really really slow! So avoid using it, or just take the styles you need.
2. If it's still long, try serving using XAMPP, dont use php artisan serve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The laravel-dompdf does not work well with php artisan serve. It take too long to show image links from the server. You should use XAMPP or another http server you like and you see your code will work.

Comment: Hey this is brilliant. I actually found it out by accident. Do h know why its slow with php artisan serve?

Answer (score 1):

You should increase max execution time, try this

```
ini_set('max_execution_time', 300); //300 seconds = 5 minutes
```

I hope this will help.